# Custom client message

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

I want to localize my error messages on my model using attributes.
I created `App_GlobalResources` and added ResourceMessages. I added
`PropertyValueInvalid`- my error message

In Global.asax I added

```
DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey = "ResorceMessages";
ValidationExtensions.ResourceClassKey = "ResorceMessages";
```

This work without if I do not have enabled client validation. But if I have

```
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

included in my master page, I get standard validation message.

How can I solve this problem?

---

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ResursPoruke))]

[Remote("ProvjeraGodine", "RemoteValidacije", "Godina nije validna")]

[Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resource), Name = "OsnovniPodaci_Godina")]

public int Godina { get; set; }

PropertyValueInvalid    Vrijednost "{0}" nije ispravna za polje: {1}
```

I should get error like;

```
Vrijednost "dkdkdkdkdk" nije ispravna za polje: Godina
```

but I get error

```
The field Godina proizvodnje must be a number.
```

If I turn of jquery validation, I get my message. 
How can I get validation message if I have jquery validations?

Answer (score 1):

You said you added a `ResourceMessages` resource, but your class key is pointing out to a different string `ResorceMessages`. Is it a typo?

```
DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey = "ResorceMessages"; <<----
ValidationExtensions.ResourceClassKey = "ResorceMessages"; <<----
```

Answer (score 0):

The default validation message is stored with the key `InvalidPropertyValue` (while the default model binder error message with the `PropertyValueInvalid")`.
However, this default message is not used if there is an error message defined already.

Comment: I can't find any documentation about the keys being used in different situations. Where did you found these keys? Using reflection?

Comment: AFAI remember I checked the source code of MVC3. I have it open if I work with MVC. I downloaded it from here: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781